# Remove occurrence of a pattern from string everywhere

Tags: text-processing, sed

I want to remove occurrence of a string from a given string. Like `/hello:` from a string like `/yo:/sup:/hello:/yo:/hello:/yup`.
And one thing for sure if string contains a colon in end then it must be removed.

There can be anything between `/hello` and colon (`:`) so I want to strip all from `/hello` to first colon (`:`).

Comment: actually there can be anything between /hello and : colon so I want to strip string from /hello to first match of colon

Comment: Please show more examples of input that would demonstrate the various cases.

Comment: @XeXkek Welcome on U&L! Please, add all your requirements to your question (instead of adding them as comment to answers). It will make easier for other users to help you.

Comment: Is this i string embedded along with other text in a file, or do you have the string in a shell variable? Where is this string?

Comment: Yes in a shell variable called PATH

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`:

```
sed --in-place 's_/hello[^:]*:__g' inputfile
```

Comment: Bro it'll strips down string to last colon not only /helloblabal: I must remove till first match of colon if it is available

Comment: Unable to replicate:  `echo "/yo:/sup:/hello:/yo:/hello:/yup" | sed 's_/hello[^:]*:__g'` yields `/yo:/sup:/yo:/yup`.

Comment: Also can colon be optional on first match?

Comment: Making the rules for one match different from the rules for the rest of the matches means you're no longer talking about a regular expression, which means it's rather difficult to do as a quick one-off.

Answer (score 0):

Perl in-line version:

```
perl -pi -e "s/\/hello//g" /path/to/file
```

or

```
perl -pi -e "s/\/hello://g" /path/to/file
```

If you want to remove the trailing : also.

Comment: It's not file it's a string

Comment: echo /yo:/sup:/hello:/yo:/hello:/yup | perl -p -e 's/\/hello://g'